# out of range error for condition statement

Tags: java

I don't understand why when I use the code below it throws the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java4.main(java4.java:11)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class java4{
public static void main (String[] args) {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter start time");
String startTime = console.nextLine();
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 );
int wage = 2;

System.out.println("Enter estimated hours work:");
String esthourswork = console.nextLine();


double wagedoubleNumber = Double.parseDouble(esthourswork);
if (starttimeHours >=06.0 && starttimeHours <=09.0 );
double totalPay = 2 * wage;
double totalPay1 = (Math.round(totalPay *100))/100.0;

 System.out.println("Total fare:$   "   + totalPay1);
```

}}

Because I think it is for this section of code:

```
   if (starttimeHours >=06 && starttimeHours <=9 );
```

With this section when I change the <=9 to <=09 it comes up with the red cross and says: 
The literal 09 of type int is out of range. But I thought int range was from 2.5 million to either way of 0.. I tried changing <=9 to <=09.0 which does not give me a red cross but still throws the same runtime error when I run it. Does anyone know how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using `String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");` before explicitly using tokens at index 0 and 1.  That is, you are assuming that whatever the user entered definitely contains at least one colon.

After you split the entered string, make sure to verify the length of your array and also make sure to verify that each individual token represents the value you want (you are using `parseDouble` - so make sure that each token contains a double value.  The easiest way would be to just surround your conversion with `try/catch` and catch `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably here

```
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
```

Make sure that lenght of your `tokens` is 2.

Comment: yes that is correct, as Alex said as well. I need to have the user enter 2 tokens with a : in between them, to aoind errors. thank you.

Comment: @user1319219 well, my answer isn't so productive (since I don't really have much time) as Alex's. I'll delete this answer as soon as you'll accept Alex's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `:` in `startTime` like `startTime.split("\\:");`

```
// error may lie here, you will get exception when user enters string which does not contain :
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");     
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]); 
// exception is thrwon from following line as tokens[] contain only one element
double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
if(tokens.length>2) {
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
```

your code would **throw indexoutofbound** when the **length of tokens is less than 2**.

Answer (score 0):

`06` is an [octal literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java, which is why `09` in an error. `09.0` is a double, but since that's not the reason you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, of course you'll still get it. See the other answers for that.